# Android Java Notify does not trigger wait

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to understand this concurrent programming with threads and I don't seem to get this wait() and notify()

I suspect that it has something to do with one of my thread waiting forever and the notify is already called. But I don't know how to solve this. I read through others posts on stackoverflow, but could not understand it well.

Here is my code and it would be helpful if someone could pinpoint me to the right direction.

```
package com.example.thread_android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("Stage", "onCreate");

    Runnable AthreadJob = new ARunnable();
    Runnable BthreadJob = new BRunnable();
    Thread myThreadOne = new Thread(AthreadJob);
    Thread myThreadTwo = new Thread(BthreadJob);
    myThreadOne.start();
    myThreadTwo.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}

class ARunnable implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run(){
    Log.d("Runnable", "A Inside Run - WAIT");
    try{
        synchronized(this){wait();}
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    //Log.d("Runnable", "A Inside Run - CONTINUE");
}
}

class BRunnable implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run(){
    Log.d("Runnable", "B Inside Run");
    synchronized (this) {notify();}
}
}
```

Comment: Don't start by learning wait and notify. These are too low-level. Learn using higher-level abstractions from the java.util.concurrent package. And if you really want to use wait and notify, at least read their javadoc, which clearly explains how they must be used, especially that wait must always be used in a loop, and that a waiting thread will be notified if another one calls notify() on the same object than the object used to wait.

Comment: you should change synchronized (this) with synchronized (MainActivity.this) and accept @Stephen answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code

```
class ARunnable implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run(){
    Log.d("Runnable", "A Inside Run - WAIT");
    try{
        synchronized(this){wait();}
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    //Log.d("Runnable", "A Inside Run - CONTINUE");
}
}
```

`this` means the running instance of `ARunnable`. This instance is actually the **thread monitor** (*An object thread locks/unlocks to execute the synchronized block*), and you have asked the current thread to `wait();`.

To make the waiting thread wake-up and run again, some other thread, holding the *same monitor* (i,e the same instance of `ARunnable`) should invoke `notify()` or `notifyAll();`. Something like below

```
class ARunnable implements Runnable{
    boolean ready = false;
    //setter for ready..
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Log.d("Runnable", "A Inside Run - WAIT");
        try{
            synchronized(this){
                if(!ready) {
                      wait();
                }
                else {
                     notifyAll(); // Now the thread which was waiting earlier, will wake-up and start resuming the execution.
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        //Log.d("Runnable", "A Inside Run - CONTINUE");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

JB Nizet's advice is sound.  Don't start learning multi-threading using wait/notify.  You should start with the higher signalling mechanisms; e.g. Semaphores, Latches, Futures, and so on.

However, the reason your code that is blocked in `wait()` in `ARunnable.run` is not seeing the `notify()` in `BRunnable.run` is that the wait and notify are being performed on different objects.  If you want one "runnable" to signal the other, they need a shared object, and they both need to `synchronize` on that object and call `wait()` and `notify` on it.